# How to call a super class method outside a class?

Tags: javascript, node.js, class, oop, ecmascript-6

I have a class BMW that extends the  class Car and override a method printModel:

```js
class Car{
    constructor(model){
        this.model = model
    }
    printModel(){
        console.log(this.model)
    }
}

class BMW extends  Car{
    constructor(model, color){
        super(model);
        this.color = color
    }
    printModel(){
        console.log(this.model, this.color)
    }
}

let bmw = new BMW('F6', 'blue')
bmw.printModel() //will print : 'F6 blue'
bmw.super.printModel()// expected: 'F6' but not working
```

How to call a class super  method on an instance of this BMW class?

Comment: There isn't really a nice way to do this, but it's also something you should never have to do in a well-designed class hierarchy, so this question likely indicates larger problems.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need a way to eventually get to `super` when calling something on the instantiation. One option is to define another method on `BMW` that calls `super.printModel`:

```js
class Car {
  constructor(model) {
    this.model = model
  }
  printModel() {
    console.log(this.model)
  }
}

class BMW extends Car {
  constructor(model, color) {
    super(model);
    this.color = color
  }
  printModelBMW() {
    console.log(this.model, this.color)
  }
  printModelCar() {
    super.printModel();
  }
}

let bmw = new BMW('F6', 'blue')
bmw.printModelBMW() //will print : 'F6 blue'
bmw.printModelCar() // expected: 'F6'
```

Comment: It's `super.printModel()`. There's no need for `super.printModel.call(this)`, it's already done due to how `super` works in ES6 classes.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to reference the super instance outside of the context of the class. If you really must use the method from the super instance from outside of the class, you can call the method yourself:

```
Car.prototype.printModel.call(bmw);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `super` keyword can only be used inside a class, not outside. It's technically possible to call `Car`'s `printModel` method directly, but this should really be avoided. The whole point of overriding a method in a superclass (like `printModel`) is to give it an implementation more appropriate to the subclass. So circumventing this is an indication of improper OO design.

However, for educational purposes I figure it would still be useful to know how this can technically be done, since it reveals how JS classes are really still using prototypes under the hood:

```
Car.prototype.printModel.call(bmw)
```

One way to improve the design to avoid this would be to add an optional argument to specify how you want to print the model:

```
class BMW extends Car{
    constructor(model, color){
        super(model)
        this.color = color
    }
    printModel(includeColor){
        if (includeColor) {
            console.log(this.model, this.color)
        }
        else super.printModel()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Car{
    constructor(model){
       this.model = model
    }
    printModel(){
    console.log(this.model)
    }
   getModel()
  {
      return this.model
  }

 }

  class BMW extends  Car{
      constructor(model, color){
        super(model);
         this.color = color
     }
     printModel(){
         console.log(super.getModel(), this.color)
     }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If parent class method needs to be used alongside with child class method, this means class design went wrong, overriding parent method was a mistake.

It could be:

```
class Car{
    ...
    printGenericModel(){
        console.log(this.model)
    }
}

class BMW extends Car{
    ...
    printModel(){
        console.log(this.model, this.color)
    }
}
```

Or in case parent class can't be refactored:

```
class Car{
    ...
    printModel(){
        console.log(this.model)
    }
}

class BMW extends Car{
    ...
    get printGenericModel(){
        return super.printModel;
    }
    printModel(){
        console.log(this.model, this.color)
    }
}
```

Both methods are available as `printGenericModel` and `printModel` on `BMW` instance.